# DataGrip connected to the live MariaDB does not display all the tables in the Database Explorer pane, only 15 are visible

Tags: datagrip

I'm using **DataGrip** v 2021.3.4 of JetBrains. I connect to **MariaDB** hosted in AWS. The database has 28 tables, though only fifteen (15) are displayed in the Database Explorer.

Interesting thing is, I can see all the tables if I go to "show visualization":
[image: DataGrip UI to select show-visualization option]

So far this is my only workaround to get to any of the 'hidden' tables, as the visualization window allows me to right-click and select "jump to source", from there I can work on the table or switch to "edit-data" if needed:
[image: Enter to source UI interface of DataGrip from visualization]

This would be an acceptable workaround if the table names and column names were recognized and hopefully auto-populated with the DataGrip interface, but instead, I get the red-underlined table names in my .SQL with errors displayed saying that:

> Unable to resolve table 'table name'

Just to clarify, executing my queries actually works and I get the expected result. The problem is that I compose my queries in the blind.

Things I've tried:

- refreshing the list of tables.
- disconnecting and reconnecting to the
  live database.
- searching for a possible solution in here, on the StackOverflow website.

Anything else you would recommend me to try?

Thank you,

**Update #1** [May 1, 2022]:
Upgraded DataGrip to 2022.1.2, removed some tables, down to 21 total, still limited to 15.
Some more details, in case this becomes a question:
MacOS v11.2.3 (BigSur), 16-core Intel-based CPU, 64Gb Memory

Comment: Try the new version of DataGrip (2022.1.2). Share the logs by creating a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE if update does not help

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I just upgraded, reopened my project - same result.
I followed your link and created a newissue report. Will post my updates in here as I get some progress on my issue.

Comment: Issue to stay up to date https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15493

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer in case it would save time for anyone landing on this post seeking to get answers to the same issue I was having.

DataGrip UI has two places where the list of visible tables can be filtered, and those filters are compound.
First is a main filter next to Data Explorer:

[image]

The second place is under **Data Sources and Drivers** -> Schemas -> Object filter options.